# How to find efficiency of a cycle thats not Carnot Cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic, carnot-cycle, efficient-energy-use

Here is the Full Question:
A monoatomic gas is expanded adiabatically from volume $V_0$ to $2V_0$ and then is brought back to the initial state through an isothermal and isochoric process respectively. Plot the P-V diagram of the complete cycle and find the efficiency of the cycle .

My general understanding of a heat engine was that it recieves heat , does work and gives back some heat . But in this case it first does work then takes heat and then gives out . Can this (giving work , taking heat ,giving heat ) take place in any order as long as its a cycle ?

also how can we calculate the efficiency of this cycle ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific sequence of processes that a cycle must have. Regardless of the cycle its efficiency is always equal to the net work done divided by the gross heat added

$$e=\frac{W_{net}}{Q_{in}}$$

Or, equivalently

$$e=\frac{Q_{in}-Q_{out}}{Q_{in}}$$

Hope this helps